# How do I control the width and height of my HTML banner?

Tags: html, css

I want to have my HTML banner width to be 915px. I have 915px in the .box-row, but the HTML banner size is 938px for some reason.

Also, how do I control the height of the HTML banner?

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tKn9f/5/

```
<div class="box-row">
<div class="box-form-body">
        <h3>
            See What You&#39;re Missing</h3>
</div>
<div class="box-form-button">
    <img alt="Learn More" height="100" src="http://www.robindelillo.fr/img/home/seeMoreButton.png" width="100" />
</div>
```

```
.box-row {
width:915px;
padding:10px;
border:1px solid #e2e3e4;
margin-top:50px;
overflow: hidden;
background-color:#f66511;
```

}

```
.box-row h3 {
    font-family:SegoeBold, Helvetica, Arial;
    font-size:1.3em;
    font-weight:normal;
    color:#fff;
    margin: 0;
}
.box-form-body {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 75%;
    padding: 0 0 0 2em;
}
.box-form-button {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 15%;
    padding: 0 0 0 2em;
}
.box-form-button img {
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

Comment: Set the padding and border to 0.

Comment: Padding and borders are added to the width.

Comment: The easiest way to see what's happening is (if you're using Chrome) to right-click on the element and then select 'Inspect Element'.  That will show you everything that goes into making it the size that it turns out to be.

Comment: or take border's `width` and `padding` off your sizes. Else you can as well look at `box-sizing` with `border-box` as value . see : http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-ui/#box-sizing0

Comment: total width=content-width+padding+border see box model for more detail

Answer (score 2):

Update your following class.

```
.box-row {
width:895px;
padding:10px;
border:1px solid #e2e3e4;
margin-top:50px;
overflow: hidden;
background-color:#f66511;
height:300px;
}
```

You can add height value to specify the height of the banner you need, minus the padding top and bottom value.

Answer (score 1):

Make your width be 895px. Since you have 10px padding on each side, that's giving you an extra 20px width. 895+20 = 915

```
.box-row {
    width:895px;
    padding:10px;
    border:1px solid #e2e3e4;
    margin-top:50px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color:#f66511;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. The width should be 895. (893 if you subtract the border width). That will give you an overall width of 915px.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the height.

Comment: `height: 300px;`

Just like the width, padding (and borders) will add to the total height. So if you have 10px padding all the way around, you need to subtract 20px to your height rule to give you the height you want.

For example, if you want a height of 200px, then use this: `height: 180px`

Answer (score 0):

if you do an inspect element you'll see that padding on left and right is set to 10 px each and also the border on left and right is set to 1 px. Total adds up to 937px.

Either you can you can remove the border and padding on the banner like so

```
.box-row {
width:915px;
/*  padding:10px;
    border:1px solid #e2e3e4;*/
margin-top:50px;
overflow: hidden;
background-color:#f66511;
}
```

or reduce the width to make it count to 915

```
.box-row {
width:893px;
padding:10px;
border:1px solid #e2e3e4;
margin-top:50px;
overflow: hidden;
background-color:#f66511;
}
```

See screenshot from chrome dev tools here

[image]

Answer (score 0):

borders widths and padding are added to width or height unless you change the box-model : http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-ui/#box-sizing0